# SourceMap or X-SourceMap handling

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

I can't get firefox (or any browser for that matter) to recognize the `X-SourceMap` header. For my code. The `//# SourceMappingURL` comment works on the browser side for me, but I can't use it for reasons specific to my system.

I am curious under what conditions the `X-SourceMap` header is used to set sourcemaps, as I don't seem to be having success. I am thinking this related to how my code is fetched -- that the devtools somehow don't 'realize' that I'm fetching a javascript file for which a sourcemap should be fetched as well.

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/5a0161f8a11e seems to show how this is implemented, but it's unclear to an eye unfamiliar with this codebase how it is determined that an `X-SourceMap` header is acted upon.

Answer (score 2):

The `X-SourceMap` header support have been checked in several browsers.

Firefox 50.1 [supports](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=x-sourcemap) `X-SourceMap` header for JavaScript files only. The `X-SourceMap` header for CSS files is not supported. The `SourceMap` header is not supported at all.

Google Chrome 50 and Chromium 55 DevTools supports both `X-SourceMap` and `SourceMap` headers for JavaScript and CSS. Although the `X-SourceMap` header is [deprecated](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114888) a few years ago.

It seems the `//# sourceMappingURL=<url>` annotation has the greatest support by browsers now. If a file changing is not applicable. a solution may be to append on the fly source maps annontations to the web server respose using some kind of a web server middleware or a mitm proxy. For example [connect-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-sourcemaps) for Node.js or the like.